# Creating an extrude in creo parametric 5

Tags: cad

I’m trying to create the following extrude.

[image]

I have created a crankshaft based on the following sketch:

[image]

I then removed material as follows, which is placed on the rear surface of the shaft.

[image]

The material is removed successfully, however my final result has a thick extruding circle around the top of the crankshaft.

[image]

What am I doing wrong ?